# Getting transition_states, geom_label_repel and enter_fade to work together

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate, ggrepel

I'm drawing a scatterplot where I'd like to highlight different observations as time passes. Sometimes, these observations are close together, so I'm using geom_label_repel to do so. I'd also like to use enter_fade and exit_fade in order to make smoother the transition between phases of the animation.

I see from elsewhere (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723567/how-to-stop-ggrepel-labels-moving-between-gganimate-frames-in-r-ggplot2)) that the position of the geom_label_repel can be made consistent with the use of a seed. However, this isn't working for me with enter_fade and exit_fade: the geom_label_repel jumps around as the labels enter and exit.

Is there a way that the geom_label_repel can stay where it is through these phases?

Here's an example of how I've attempted to implement this, which hopefully will illustrate the problem I'm running into.

[image]

```
set.seed(24601)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(ggrepel)

x <- 
  rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y <- 
  rnorm(100, 0, 1)
names <- 
  stri_rand_strings(100,
                    5)
categories <- 
  rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 5)

ggplot(data.frame(x, y, names, categories)) + 
  aes(x = x,
      y = y) + 
  geom_point(data = . %>% 
               select(- categories)) + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = names,
                       group = categories),
                   seed = 24601) + 
  transition_states(categories)  + 
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_fade()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that during the transitions, the location and number of labels within the plot are not consistent. This causes `geom_label_repel()` to force labels away from each other. You can set `force = 0` so that your labels are not repelled from each other (default force is `1`), but instead only repelled from points.

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x, y, names, categories)) + 
  aes(x = x,
      y = y) + 
  geom_point(data = . %>% 
               select(- categories)) + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = names,
                       group = categories),
                   seed = 24601,
                   force = 0) + 
  transition_states(categories)  + 
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_fade()
```

[image]

As you can see, you will have some labels overlap. However, if important, you could play with lower values of force (e.g. `force = 0.1`) so the labels only shift slightly but overlap less.

Although most are stable, I am getting a couple of random labels popping up and not transitioning, will investigate.

Comment: This looks great, thanks. I’ll play around with different values of force and see how I get on!